# Check if a server can be found like in the safari app

Tags: swift, safari, wkwebview

at first I have to excuse me because of my language and programming skills. I`m just learning English and programming ;-)

Now to my question:
In my app i basically just want to implement a web-browser. The web-browser ist working fine but if I wan`t to load a link which not exists it just shows white. I also have tried it with

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
```

but if "http://" is at the front it always returns true.

I just want to have it like in Safari as you see in the picture.
If you enter a random link it should say that the link can´t be opend.

Has anyone a idea how this can be implemented?

Comment: Have you looked into the `navigationDelegate` of `WKWebView`?

Comment: Oh thanks, thats a brilliant suggestion. Which method do I have to take?

Comment: See `WKNavigationDelegate`. It should be obvious which method to use to check for failure.

Comment: I found it myself. It`s     func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
  }